# Randomly distributed cases according to census data

Tags: r, census, geolocation, administrative-boundaries, random

I'd like to randomly place a point within a geographic boundary with the caveat that I would like to use census data so that points are randomly placed according to population density (i.e. more likely to be placed where there is higher population density).  I would ideally like to do this using the R programming language.

I am not a GIS person, so I am not entirely certain of how to do this. I have some census data and  I have my boundary co-ordinates (as a shapefile, and this I know how to use), but how I go about combining the two and more so, placing a point randomly according to census data is where I get a little stumped.

Comment: I've never tried this, but it sounds like [weighted random selection](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=weighted+random+selection) - some of the code samples under this search may help you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually asking two questions. One is how to merge census data to your shape file. This is not very difficult, you may want to check out `merge` or `spCbind`, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652472). It hard to say without knowing the structure of your data.

The second question is about how to do the weighted sampling. I have a suggestion below that uses `spsample` from the `sp` package. It is a very crude example, without knowing specifics of your data.

```
library(sp)

#make up some polys with population
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3), "3")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
population <- data.frame(pop=c(30, 100, 250), row.names=sapply(slot(SpP, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))) 
SpDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, population)

# make up some samplesize, directly correlated to population density
samplesize <- round(SpDF$pop/sapply(slot(SpDF, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "area"))) 

# sample
s <- sapply(slot(SpDF, 'polygons'), function(i) spsample(i, n=samplesize[as.integer(i@ID)], type='random'))

plot(SpDF); plot (s.merged, add=T, pch = 20, col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying to understand my data too - I will try out your recommendations and see how they work out.

Comment: @user4673: if you can post your data or a representative example that might help.